# Getting cross origin request blocked on Opencart

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

Previously, the website was doing fine but these month it keep getting this error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://xxxs.com/index.php?route=account/account/country&country_id=129.
>   (Reason: missing token ‘x-requested-with’ in CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://xxxs.com/index.php?route=account/register/customfield&customer_group_id=1.
>   (Reason: missing token ‘x-requested-with’ in CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://xxxs.com/index.php?route=extension/module/ocquickview/appendcontainer.
>   (Reason: missing token ‘x-requested-with’ in CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

**Noted that xxxs in example domain
I have tried to add this to .htaccess but it's still happened for some module.

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: I'm suddenly getting CORS errors as well. Preflight request returns correct headers. And the actual request has a 200 OK status, but no response. Browser console displays "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" (both in Chrome and Firefox). Everything was working fine until a week ago...